# iCloud developer dashboard containers not showing up

Tags: ios, containers, icloud, cloudkit, dashboard

I have enabled CloudKit within the iOS app capabilities and I'm using the default container with no errors on setup. Im an admin in my development team. I have checked the app id lists (online) and the container does exist but when I go to the dashboard and try to select the container to create new record/fields, I can't because the container isn't there when I go to select it. It's missing from the dashboard console. Please help.

Comment: You have to wait a bit